# COBOL Linux compiling error - reiteration

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cobol

I posted an issue I was having a few days ago with compiling on COBOL, I have since uninstalled and reinstalled all the necessary extensions (COBOL, Micro focus, etc.).  After reset, I now get this compiling error: **assignment1.cob:14: warning: line not terminated by a newline [-Wothers]**

Here is the code used, and provided by the textbook:

```
1       identification division.
2       program-id. assignment1.
3
4       environment division.
5       configuration section.
6
7       data division.
8       working-storage section.
9       01 out pic x(11) value "Hello World".
10      procedure division.
11       display out.
12       goback.
13
14      end program assignment1.
```

What is causing this error?

Uninstall, reinstall, enable/disable extensions, added proper ruler settings

Comment: the error say you need to press enter at the end of that last line, have you tried that?

Comment: adding the line 15 (hitting enter) now produces this error: assignment1.cob:8: error: syntax error, unexpected Literal, expecting .

Comment: well that code compiles fine at jdoodle

Comment: please update the question to include your new code.

Comment: ok so after adding that line 15, somehow it added a 2 at the end of  working storage section, oddly.  After catching that it now compiles!  Thank you Joop

Comment: Note: This is a **warning** not an **error**. Some programs have problems with reading "unfinished" lines (and for example on GitHub and other places you'll see a red end mark on those files in source views, too); and the warning is there to fix that before wondering why other programs use that.Think of pre-parsers for `EXEC SQL`, tools for querying/refactoring the code, ...